# What do I change in top of the file after I moved the project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, forms, webforms

I'am taking over a and doing same small modifications to a small projekt and moving it to another folder, all files are in the same filer (before "Form" and now "Upload")

```
Form
/PublicWebSite/Web/Form
To
/PublicWebSite/Web/Upload
```

If I look in the top of the files it looks like this

```
<%@ Page language="c#" Codebehind="UploadForm.aspx.cs" 
AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="Episerver.Form.UploadForm" "%>
```

Do I need to change Inherits to

```
Episerver.Upload.UploadForm
```

Or can I just have

```
Inherits="UploadForm"
```

Because all files are in the same filer?

Do I need to change anything in the top of the files and what do I need to change?

Comment: The file location does not matter, `Inherits` is looking for a _namespace_.  Generally you want your namespaces to match the folder structure they are in, but you have to modify the namespaces on your files for that to happen

Comment: `Or can I just have` What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Any luck? did you see my answer?

Answer (score 0):

- Web Form: UploadForm.aspx
- Code Behind: UploadForm.aspx.cs

Web Form:

```
<%@ Page language="c#" Codebehind="UploadForm.aspx.cs" 
    AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="Episerver.Form.UploadForm" "%>
```

Code Behind, should match `Inherits`:

```
public partial class Episerver.Form.UploadForm : System.Web.UI.Page
```

But, dots/periods are problematic. Hyphens are better -- and they are converted to underscores. So `Inherits` should probably looks like

```
Inherits="Episerver_Form_UploadForm"
```

Code Behind, should match:

```
public partial class Episerver_Form_UploadForm : System.Web.UI.Page
```

or in your new case, using the Upload folder (root/Upload/UploadForm.aspx):

```
Inherits="Upload_UploadForm"
```

Code Behind, should match:

```
public partial class Upload_UploadForm : System.Web.UI.Page
```